# Forms thorughs required field error hence I clear model after push to list in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have two required fields in my Form. When I click an add button, model values push to one list and shows using ng-repeat. After that, It throughs  required field error, hence I cleared both models as empty.

Kindly check my sample code

```
<body ng-controller="testcontrollerApp">
<div ng-app="testcontroller">
<form name="TestForm" id="TestForm">
    <div>
        <ul class="remove-style">
            <li ng-repeat="test in tests">
                <span>Name :   {{test.name}}</span>
                <span>ID   :   {{test.id}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="inputs"><span>Name</span><span><input type="text" ng-model="item.txtname" required/></span></div>
        <div class="inputs"><span>Id</span><span><input type="text" ng-model="item.txtid" required/></span></div>            
        <input type="submit" ng-click="btnclick()" value="Add" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        debugger;
        var testcontrollerApp = angular.module('testcontrollerApp', []);
        testcontrollerApp.controller("testcontroller", function ($scope) {                                
            $scope.tests = [
                { 'name': 'Test1', 'id': 'id1' }
            ];
            $scope.btnclick = function () {
                debugger;
                if ($scope.TestForm.$valid !== false) {
                    $scope.tests.push({ 'name': $scope.item.txtname, 'id': $scope.item.txtid });
                    $scope.item.txtname = '';
                    $scope.item.txtid = '';
                    $scope.TestForm.$setPristine();
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
</form></div></body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `ng-click` from your input to `ng-submit` in the form:

```
ng-submit="btnclick()"
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fa50jSJdFTdUBhhFaCc?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's working fine, i am the beginner of this AngularJS. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
input type="reset" value="Add"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.